# Why OpenCV HaarCascade Doesnt Work Properly

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, haar-classifier

I have a school project. so I am new to opencv but I have done some practices before I have started to my project.

I have my own cascade dataset, in which [I have made with](https://amin-ahmadi.com/cascade-trainer-gui/).

So in my project, I am trying to detect right forks in a road on google maps. I have screenshots from google maps. Lets give two example:

#### Positive one

[image]

#### Negative one

[image]

I have approximately 100 negative and 60-80 positive image.

But when I try to start my code, it doesnt find any right fork in a road.
I couldnt understand why it is not working, but can you please help me? Any suggestions would be great to solve this issue...

```
This is my code:
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('photos\IMG_4562.png')
cv.imshow('Right Way', img)

gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv.imshow('Gray Rright Way', gray)

haar_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('resimler\cascade.xml')#dosyayı aldık

right_recs = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=1)

print(f'Number of right ways found = {len(right_recs)}')

for (x,y,w,h) in faces_rect:
    cv.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), thickness=2) #burada bir tane dikdörtgen çizmiş oluyoruz aslında. ve bu dikdörtgen de direkt haarcascade in sayesinde yüz olan bölüme geliyor

cv.imshow('Detected Right Ways Are Here', img)



cv.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Did you train the model based on the positive and negative dataset that was prepared beforehand?

Comment: no, I tried to made it

Comment: like it was mine dataset, Mine own photos